# how to check database connection exist or not and close connection and reconnect to database in cakephp 3.7

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

in cakephp 2 available database connection close and reconnect and check exist database or not.

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($datasource);
   // pr($db);exit;
   $config_settings = $db->config;
   if($is_multi_host_exist == 0){
       $username = $config_settings['login'];
       $password = $config_settings['password'];
       $host = $config_settings['host'];
   }
   $db->setConfig(array(
       'host' => $host,
       'login' => $username,
       'password' => $password,
       'database' => $this->dynamic_database_prefix.$company_id
       )
   );
   try{ // If connection established
       $db->close();
       $db->reconnect();
       if(!$db->isConnected()) {
           //$this->error('!$db->isConnected()');
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   } catch(Exception $e){  // Error in connection  
       return false;
   }
```

above code is working with cakephp 2.
same like how to write cakephp 3.7

Comment: https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.Database.Connection.html

Comment: already i am working on that not able to achieve the thing. thanks for your suggestions. if you have any samples can help me out on this.

Comment: Perhaps show what CakePHP3 code you've got so far?